# Accuracy and Validation Accuracy of pretrained model is not changed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 600 000 images and I want to classify them using keras. I am just trying the pretrained model on greyscale images. And I am trying to use the model architecture of pre-trained models like resnet50, inceptionv3, etc. But accuracy and validation accuracy of the model has not changed which is stuck at 67%. I tried changing the network, applying more epochs and also changing the pretrained model, but I always get the same result like 67% accuracy and validation accuracy. I don't understand why I am getting the same result. Please recommended some ideas on how can I solve this problem. [This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHaJ5.png). In this steps_per_epochs = no. of images/batch size and batch size is 128.No of images in the training dataset is 479369 and in the validation dataset is 136962.[This is the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpzd9.png).

Comment: Please try avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Comment: Sure Sir. I'll take care.

Comment: Without code there is nothing to be said here, also do not address people as "sir".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a pre-trained model. so, that is why it gets showed the same accuracy. my suggestion is to change the pre-trained model and tryna your custom model and then see the changes.

Comment: Sir, I also used my custom model and I got 92 % accuracy but now I am trying the pretrained model on medical images. Is there any way that I can use a pre-trained model for my medical problem description?

Comment: did you train the model on the same dataset? or are you using a pre-trained model for a different dataset?

Comment: Yes, I trained both custom CNN and pretrained models on the same dataset.

Comment: sounds good. can you just show your code so I can better understand who's the blocker?